# Javascript - Set interval

Tags: javascript

I created a script where it will get lat and lon from sql and place a marker on the google map embedded, And I want to run the script every second like is auto getting data and place marker automatically.

```
 <script>
    var infoWindow= null;
    var map = null;
    var markersArray = [];


        function initMap() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(14.657971, 120.976970);
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 16,
          streetViewControl : false,
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        });

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        updateMaps();

function updateMaps() { 


      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file

      downloadUrl('phpsqlajax_genxml.php?t=', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');

              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label

              });


              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);

                });
            });
          });
        }


      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}

        }
        window.setInterval(updateMaps, 1000);       
    </script>
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and actually provide a **question** for us to answer.

Comment: Ok? Well evidently you know `setInterval` can help you do that, so what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
var update;

function updateInterval() {
  update = setInterval(function() {
    updateMaps()
  }, 1000);
}
updateInterval();
```

You have to use JQuery to load updateInterval() when the document is ready or write `<script>updateInterval();</script>` at the end of the body.

Comment: You have to add `()` behind the function name in order to call it, or just use the function name as the first argument instead of wrapping it in an anonymous function